# Asp.net core caching jwk during jwt validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm relativly new to .NET. I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1. I am handing authentication using JWTs. 
As part of the jwt validation I call out to the issuer and get their public key to check my tokens integritry. So I do:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Authority"];
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
        };
    });
```

This does what I expect however it seems to go out to the issuing server for every request. What I would like is to cache the
jwk I get back and only try to hit the authority if the validation fails(this could be because of key rotation, for example). 
What is strange is I'm not seeing an obvious way to define a caching policy in the configuration. I feel like this is a pretty
standard use case and I might be missing something but I'm not having any luck looking through the docs. Could anyone suggest an 
approach for me here? Would I have to roll my own IConfigurationManager to enforce this? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks
much!

Comment: You may be able to solve this by implementing your own IssuerSigningKeyResolver. This article describes how to make one that reads keys from a configuration file but presumably you could also retrieve the jwk and cache it: https://www.carlrippon.com/asp-net-core-web-api-multi-tenant-jwts/